# WPF XAML Namespace issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

Using the following code:

```
<ad:DockingManager x:Class="Main.AvalonDock.Views.AvalonDockView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ad="clr-namespace:AvalonDock;assembly=AvalonDock" 
             xmlns:cal="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="293" d:DesignWidth="504">
    <ad:ResizingPanel Margin="0,10,0,10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <ad:DockablePane cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainLeftRegion" Name="leftDockablePane" />
        <ad:DocumentPane cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainCenterRegion" Name="mainDocumentPane" />
        <ad:DockablePane cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRightRegion" Name="rightDockablePane" />
    </ad:ResizingPanel>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

My projects name is Main.AvalonDock which uses the AvalonDock control. It will not compile because of a discrepancy between the ad namespace and the project namespace. Is there a workaround?

heres the error:

> The type or namespace name
>   'DockablePane' does not exist in the
>   namespace
>   'Main.AvalonDock'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

Comment: Have you tried putting a semi-colon in the project name to see if that's the problem? Change your project name to "Main.Avalon_Dock" temporarily and see if that's the issue. I don't think there's anyway to change or modify the way XAML namespaces are resolved.

Comment: @Josh G - Yep, that corrects the issue. Its definitely related to the names being too similar.

Comment: The problem is though that I'm stubborn and I don't want to have to rename my project to accommodate a third party control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the AvalonDockView.g.cs (or AvalongDockView.g.vb) in your projects obj folder, you will see the underlying issue.

Basically, you'd end up with something like:

```
using Main.AvalonDock.Views {
    internal AvalonDock.DockablePane leftDockablePane;
    // ...
}
```

Using the C# type resolution specs, the AvalonDock resolves to your namespace, not the one in the AvalonDock assembly.